# How to use rspec to test ActiveRecord model scopes and queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I am trying to write rspec-rails tests on my ActiveRecord `Flight` object scopes (e.g. `#around_date`). Here's one test I've written:

```
  let(:flight) { create(:flight) } 
  date = DateTime.new(year=2023, month=12, day=25)

  it 'selects within default date range' do
    flights = Flight.around_date(date.to_s).to_a
    expect flights.to include(flight)
  end
```

This is supposed to test that the `#around_date` scope will return the `Flight` object created with `let`. (The factory creates them with the date 12-25-2023).

Here is the code for the `#around_date` scope within the `Flight` model:

```
scope :around_date, ->(date_string, day_interval = 1) {
    if date_string.present?
      date = Date.parse(date_string)

      lower_date = date - day_interval.days
      upper_date = date + day_interval.days
      where(start_datetime: (lower_date..upper_date))
    end
  }
```

When I run the test I get the following error message:

```
 Failure/Error: expect flights.to include(flight)
 
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `>=' for #<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::ContainExactly:0x00007fe400279098 @expected=[#<Flight id: 1, departure_airport_id: 2, arrival_airport_id: 1, start_datetime: "2023-12-25 00:00:00.000000000 +0000", duration_minutes: 30, created_at: "2023-12-02 16:51:32.363329000 +0000", updated_at: "2023-12-02 16:51:32.363329000 +0000">]>
 # ./spec/models/flight_spec.rb:11:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
```

I'm lost as to what this error message means as there is no case of `>=` anywhere in the relevant code.

Any ideas as to what this error message could mean would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may be troubleshooting the wrong test... the error indicates a failure in `expect flights.to match_array(created_flights)` but the test you've shown has the expectation `expect(flights).to include(flight)`. btw that's not exactly what you typed (parens around 'flights'), did you make a typo in your question or in your code?

Comment: You're right. There was a typo in the question. I tried to use match_array instead of include but they both return the same error to do with the '>='. I fixed the question.

Comment: there's still a typo, and I don't know if it's in your code or just the question. `expect flights.to include(flight)` should have parens around 'flights'.So `expect(flights).to include(flight)`

Comment: Sorry, I had copied and pasted the wrong error message. The typos are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your test should be:

```
let(:flight) { create(:flight) }  
date = DateTime.new(year=2023, month=12, day=25)

it 'selects within default date range' do   
  flights = Flight.around_date(date.to_s).to_a   
  expect(flights).to include(flight) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

expect now accepts the block so pass **flights**  within the block.

```
it 'selects within default date range' do
  flights = Flight.around_date(date.to_s).to_a
  expect {flights}.to include(flight)
end
```